# How to combine result of lapply to a data.frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say, I have a vector and a function with one argument which returns a data.frame.
I want to apply the function to each element of the vector and combine the results to one big data.frame.

I've got the working command below with lapply and rbind. But it looks to me a little bit "unnatural". Is there a better, more clear way?
I've got some ideas with plyr but I would like to avoid plyr because I would like to use dplyr instead.

```
 my_vector <- c(1,2,3)
 my_function <- function(a){
   unif <- runif(a)
   norm <- rnorm(a)
   return(data.frame(unif=unif, norm=norm))
 }

 as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,(lapply(my_vector, my_function))))
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(my_vector, my_function) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: Note that the parentheses for `bind_rows()` aren't required since there are no additional arguments - check out ?magrittr::\`%>%\` for more details.

Comment: @PeterDiakumis do you have paranthesis-phobia?

Comment: @ÖmerAn back then I was afraid of two extra keystrokes per function, yes ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `data.table`'s `rbindlist` as follows:

```
require(data.table)
df <- setDF(rbindlist(lapply(my_vector, my_function)))
```

Without `setDF` rbindlist returns a `data.table` instead of a `data.frame`

Comment: I realize this is from a long time ago, but I'm trying to achieve the output from your answer above while also having a column with the information from `my_vector`.  Is that possible?  I need to know which row corresponds to which object inside of `my_vector`

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is a join. Try googling for that "dplyr join" or "data.table join"

Comment: I don't know how I would make that join work.  What would I join on?  `my_vector` is just a vector and the output `df` doesn't have that information (or else I wouldn't need the join).  Plus the number of rows output from each vector object is different so I can't simply manually enter it with a `seq` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Solution for nested lists:

```
  result = bind_rows(lapply(list1, function(x) {
    bind_rows(lapply(list2, function(y) {
      lapply(list3, function(z) {
        read.delim(paste0(x, "_", y, "_", z))
      })
    }))
  }))
```